# Style for chat top bar is broken

Tags: bug, design, chat

Where to find: the main chat domain. For example https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ or https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ both have the same problem:

SE chat:
[image: Stack Exchange main chat page. The user information is in the top left corner.]

SO chat:
[image: Stack Overflow main chat page. The user information is in the top left corner.]

On the top, the user information and search is all the way to the left. Seems either some styling is missing or it is broken.